# Django display related count

Tags: django, templates, count, categories

i currently try to display who many posts a category has.
Therefor i created the Post Model and the Category Model (See below):

**models.py**

```
# Categorys of Post Model
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Title")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
        ordering = ['title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

#Post Model
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name="Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    postattachment = fields.FileField(upload_to='postattachment/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, null=True)
    postcover = fields.ImageField(upload_to='postcover/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, null=True, dependencies=[
        FileDependency(processor=ImageProcessor(
            format='JPEG', scale={'max_width': 300, 'max_height': 300}))
    ])
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**category_list.html**

```
{% extends 'quickblog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for categories in categories %}
        <div>
            <h1><u>{{ categories.title }} {{ $NumCountGetHere }}</u></h1>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Now i have no idea how to get the related objects counted...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
{% for cat in categories %}
    <div>
        <h1><u>{{ cat.title }} {{ cat.post_set.count }}</u></h1>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The model `Post` has a `Foreignkey` field to the model `Category`. You can access the related `Post` instances from a given `Category` instance using the manager `category_instance.post_set`. Read about it in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

Finally, we use the method `.count()` on this manager to get the number of related posts for that given category. This way the code ends up looking like `{{ cat.post_set.count }}`.

Comment: where did you get your `{{ cat.post_set.count }}`?

Comment: @VincentDapiton I added more info with a link to the relevant Django docs section